# class path resource [myfile.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path in Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, classpath

I have a file in my SpringBoot Application -

```
src/main/resources/myfile.xml
```

My application is running in a docker container.
In my pom I've specified -

```
 <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/myfile.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/docker</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources> ...
```

In my code I try to access this file with -

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("myfile.xml").getFile();
String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But I'm getting -

```
class path resource [myfile.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/home/dockeruser/service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myfile.xml
```

Does anybody have some insight/tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: Because it isn't a file. A `File` in java is an actual resource on the file system. As this is packaged in a jar it isn't a `File` in that sense. Instead use `getInputStream` and use that to read the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer-

```
   InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + "myfile.xml");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String input = writer.toString();
```

The leading slash is important.

Comment: Why? As I stated use `getInputStream` instead of `getFile`. and you can use the `StreamUtils` from spring to efficiently read the content to a `String`.